# syntax erro: unexpected "WHERE" (where) in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is my code:

```
SELECT s_num, SUM(qty)
FROM　S,SPJ
WHERE S.s_num=SPJ.s_num1
GROUP BY s_num
HAVING SUM(qty)>1000;
```

but I have

> syntax error: unexpected "WHERE" (where)

Please help me!

Comment: While I would agree with the answer below to change to an explicit INNER JOIN, the actual problem here appears to be the space between FROM and S. Playing around with your SQL it doesn't actually appear to be a space (ie, if I cut and past it I get the error, if I replace the _space_ between FROM and S with a real space then it avoids the error).

Comment: Thank you very much. replacing the space with a real space works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner join for the same result as below :

```
SELECT        S.s_num, SUM(S.qty) AS Expr1
FROM            S INNER JOIN
                         SPJ ON S.s_num = SPJ.s_num1
GROUP BY S.s_num
HAVING        (SUM(S.qty) > 1000)
```